# Cython wrapping C++ virtual function

Tags: python, c++, cython

In C++ header declaration:

```cpp
class MdSpi
{ 
    public:
        virtual void OnFrontConnected(){};
        virtual void OnFrontDisconnected(int nReason){};
        virtual void OnHeartBeatWarning(int nTimeLapse){};
}

class MdApi
{
public:

    static MdApi *CreateMdApi(const char *FlowPath = "");

    virtual void Release() = 0;

    virtual void Init() = 0;

    virtual int Join() = 0;

    virtual const char *GetTradingDay() = 0;

    virtual void RegisterFront(char *pszFrontAddress) = 0;

    virtual void RegisterSpi(MdSpi *pSpi) = 0;
protected:
    ~MdApi(){};
}
```

Cython document don’t provide any introduction about the C++ virtual or pure virtual function.

I know how to define the c++ header inherit from the virtual class.

```cpp
class WrapMdSpi  : public MdSpi
{
public:
    WrapMdSpi();
    ~ WrapMdSpi();

    virtual void OnFrontConnected();
    virtual void OnFrontDisconnected(int nReason);
    virtual void OnHeartBeatWarning(int nTimeLapse);
};
```

In the main.cpp:

```cpp
#include “MdSpi.h”

MdSpi g_MdSpi;
MdApi *g_MdApi = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  g_MdApi = CKSGMdApi::CreateMdApi();
  g_MdApi->RegisterSpi(&g_MdSpi);
  g_MdApi->Init();
  g_MdApi->Release();

  return 0;
}
```

How could I define the virtual function in the `pxd` or how could I define the `pyx` files?